# Magento 2 : How to Override vendor files in my custom theme

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, overrides

How to override below admin file in my custom admin theme ?

```
/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml
```

Answer (score 2):

> Front-end and Back-end theme have same file structure.For customize or change something from the parent theme all you need to do is copy the file you want to change (layout, template) to your theme from the specific module and do your changes.

**Points to remember:**

- To create the back-end/front-end theme, you need to create a new module
- To apply front-end theme you can active from back-end.

**Reference:** http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-apply.html

- To apply back-end theme you need to specify in `etc/di.xml` file

**Reference:** http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_apply.html

**1. How to create admin theme**

**create theme.xml:**  file in `app/design/adminhtml/<yourpackage>/<yourtheme>/theme.xml`

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>My Theme Tile</title>
    <parent>Magento/backend</parent> 
</theme>
```

**Register theme :**
create **registration.php** in `app/design/adminhtml/<yourpackage>/<yourtheme>/registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'adminhtml/yourpackage/yourtheme',
    __DIR__
);
```

**module.xml:** in `app/design/adminhtml/<yourpackage>/<yourtheme>/theme.xml` and   `sequence xml` element to make sure your theme gets loaded last.

```
<config>
    <module name="<yourpackage>_<yourtheme>" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Enable theme:**

**etc/di.xml:** `app/design/adminhtml/<yourpackage>/<yourtheme>/etc/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">yourpackage/yourtheme</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

[image]

> Now run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`  and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`  from your magento root directory

**Override**

> Now theme all set come to customize part if you need to change any file just copy from `Magento_root_directory\vendor\magento\` for frontend and  back-end.

**Example:**

**Override sales order view page :** 
just need to create **xml file** in your module to override.

`app/code/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml` 
               copy from 
`Magento-root-directory\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\layout\sales_order_view.xml`

```
<referenceBlock name='order_info'>
  <arguments>
    <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Vendor_Module::order/view/info.phtml</argument>
  </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Don't forget to add Load custom module layout after sales

> app/code/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/etc/module.xml

```
<sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
</sequence>
```

and all changes here..

> app/design/adminhtml/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/Magento_Sales/templates/order/view/info.phtml

Comment: Thanks for reply. do you have any idea how to create and apply custom admin theme in backend

Comment: I have created http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html this way but didn;t apply my theme in admin

Comment: Do we need to create module.xml  in 
   app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/Themename/module.xml and etc/di.xml in  app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/Themename/etc/di.xml

Comment: Create a separate MyVendor_MyBackendTheme module and specify in  '<module>/etc/di.xml'

Comment: @hweb87 The steps are the same, but instead of frontend use adminhtml in the folder structure.

Comment: ok, Let me try and update you

Comment: <module name="My_Custommodule" setup_version="2.0.0"> which module name we need to use? do we need to use Magento_Sales?

Comment: replace MY_Custommodule with you module name like Vendor_moduleName

Comment: wait i'm updating answer step by step with explanation !

Comment: I want to apply my admin theme to all page like frontend.

In frontend if I will create my custom theme in inspect element it's show css from my theme but it's inherit parent theme

Comment: just create backend and frontend theme and override what you want . magento have fallback system if it didn't get from your theme it would get it from parent theme. which you have mention.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76627/discussion-between-lalit-mohan-and-hweb87).

Comment: Message me when you will upate

Comment: Can you please share with me your code zip file

Answer (score 0):

Try `app/design/adminhtml/<Vendor>/<admin_theme>/Magento_Sales/templates/order/view/info.phtml`

You can read on how to create an admin theme at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html

Comment: I have created admin theme but how to apply in admin ? do you have any idea ?

Comment: @hweb87 You can go through http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_apply.html to have information about applying admin theme.

Answer (score -1):

Create `app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Sales/templates/order/view/info.phtml` in your custom admin theme.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: No, we can't edit in module-sales

Comment: Add info.phtml in your custom theme at  module-sales/templates/order/view/info.phtml
We are overriding the core template.