# Magento 2 : override phtml file issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, overrides, phtml

I faced problem with overriding a `phtml` file in Magento 2.

**I want this:-**

*(1) Core Module of `phtml` **Override By** Custom Module called - A*

*(2) Same `phtml` file of Module - A **Override By**  Some Custom Module - B*

**Example**:-
Magento_Sales::order/view/info.phtml

This file override by Module-A And I want override Module - A `info.phtml`  in my custom Module-B

**Issue:-**
So that the issue will arise that Module - B cannot override that `phtml` file.

Comment: can you please share with me your phtml file path and where you want to override ?

Comment: @hweb87 I just edited the question.

Comment: Do you want to override adminhtml file ?
/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml

Comment: yes, I want to override this file but this file already overrides  Module-A, I want to override the same file with Module-B.

Comment: May be this will help to you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/223916/magento-2-how-to-override-vendor-files-in-my-custom-theme

Comment: I don't want to create a theme for this file.  @hweb87

Comment: Without creating theme you can't override adminhtml file in your theme

Comment: I don't want to override a `phtml` in the theme, I want to override in my custom module @hweb87

Comment: Share with me you Custom Module A and B path

Comment: @Divyesh Did you find a solution for this? If so please share it as an answer. I am also facing the same issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to override the core .phtml file.
You can refer to the below link for more information.
https://webkul.com/blog/override-phtml-file-magento2/

To call your phtml file at the place of core(Magento's) file, you need to follow:

Firstly, create an xml file with the controller name, on which page you want to override.

For example: here we override checkout/cart/index controller page file.

create checkout_cart_index.xml inside :

app/code/Webkul/Hello/view/frontend/layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Webkul_Hello::cart.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Here,

checkout.cart : is block name, whose template file you want to override.

Webkul_Hello::cart.phtml : is a template file of your module.

Now, create cart.phtml file at location:

app/code/Webkul/Hello/view/frontend/templates folder

```
//write your stuff here
<h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have mentioned proper module sequence that is very important for overriding.
You may check your module sequence is correct or not to view app/etc/config.php in this file all the modules listed enable/disable with sequence which one is going to load first. if your module B loading before A then phtml will not be override.
For more details please refer Magento guide.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Vendor_ComponentB" setup_version="0.0.1">
    <sequence>
    <!-- Vendor_ComponentB is dependent on Vendor_ComponentA: -->
        <module name="Vendor_ComponentA" />
    </sequence>
</module>
```

Comment: you are right but this not a solution of my issue because this is merged layout, but this will not override `phtml`. I had already tried this.